# What is the difference between the multilevel/hierarchical models and including the moderator variable in multiple regression analysis?

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction, multilevel-analysis

I would like to ask about the difference between applying the multilevel/hierarchical models and including the moderator variable in multiple regression analysis. This is for considering the individual differences in the context of my study. Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It would help I you could show sample code illustrating the difference in models that you would like to understand.